# Obfuscate a Single Java Class File using Third party tool

Tags: encryption, obfuscation

I'm currently looking for some tool which can Obfuscate a Single Class file. Where it would be better when you suggest me some tool for Control flow obfuscation.I have tried proguard, DashO, and some tool where it doesn't supports the Class file and supports Jar. I have also tried JShrink where it can accept Class file and Obfuscate it which I would prefer some similar tools.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: (Disclaimer: I work for PreEmptive Solutions, we make DashO.) You should be able to obfuscate a single class with DashO, and if you have registered a trial, you will have access to our support team to work out issues like this. Otherwise, please provide some detail about what you tried, what you expected, and what did not work as expected.

Comment: hey Neuralmer. What I want to know is "Can I Obfuscate a Single Class file(Just a Class file as a input and i want  a Class file as a output) with Control flow obfuscation method wih DashO

Comment: (Disclaimer: I work for PreEmptive Solutions, we make DashO.) DashO can obfuscate a single class. You can do this by adding, as an input, a directory containing just that class. Certain DashO obfuscation features will add classes, however, resulting in more than one class being output. Please direct any further questions to our support team.